# spring-data-redis: How to disable pubsub event

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-redis

```
// org/springframework/session/data/redis/RedisIndexedSessionRepository.java
@Override
    public void save(RedisSession session) {
        session.save();
        if (session.isNew) {
            String sessionCreatedKey = getSessionCreatedChannel(session.getId());
            this.sessionRedisOperations.convertAndSend(sessionCreatedKey, session.delta);
            session.isNew = false;
        }
    }
```

I got error: ERR command 'PUBLISH' is not allowed.(Reids server disabled PUBLISH command)